# Unable to use nrc

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I write because I have a problem in Rstudio when loading the "nrc" sentiment set. First of all, for this I have loaded both the textdata library and the tidytext library. And besides, the afinn dictionary and bing don't give me any kind of problem.

The error comes because when applying the function: get_sentiments("nrc") I get the following:

"If you use this lexicon, quote it.

1: Yes 2: No"

If I put 1, I get the following: Error: '~/Library/Caches/textdata/nrc/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-v0.92/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-Wordlevel-v0.92. txt' does not exist. And if I put 2, it doesn't work directly for me.

I am attaching a screenshot so you can see it more clearly.

I have tried to uninstall and install the packages, update them, etc... but nothing works for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egZWc.png)

Comment: What version of `textdata` are you using? It seems there was a problem that was recently fixed in 0.4.2 https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/issues/211. It's also possible the suggestion here may help: https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/issues/189